# How to convert or manipulate JPEG stored as blob without image library

Tags: image-processing, google-apps-script, jpeg

I have a JPEG image stored in memory as a blob and am looking to apply some basic transformations to it (e.g. resize, convert to greyscale, rotate etc.)

I am currently using Google Scripts which doesn't have a native image library as far as I can tell.

Are there standard algorithms or similar which would allow me to work with the raw binary array, knowing it represents a JPEG image, to achieve such a transformation?

Comment: I assumed the raw binary array you mentioned is the raw set of pixels?  If that's the case, you'll need a decoder to decompress the blob into raw binary array.  Can't you flush the blob to a server and get the raw set of pixels in the response?

Comment: @GaryTsui No, not raw pixels like a bitmap would be, rather the binary representation of an encoded JPEG image.

Comment: In that case, you basically have the complete JPEG image (incl header, quantization table etc)?

Comment: I would start by reading this T. 81 http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf

Comment: In standard javascript you could do this with canvas. There's an issue open for google to add canvas support to apps-script but it doesn't appear to be there yet: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=425

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you are looking for I guess, but...

To be able to do image processing using JPEG files as input, you need to decode the images. Well, actually, 90/180/270 degree rotation, flipping and cropping is possible as lossless operations, and thus without decoding the image data. But for anything more advanced, like resizing, you need to work with a decoded image.

Both the file structure (JIF/JFIF) and algorithms used to compress the image data in standard JPEG format are well defined and properly documented. But at the same time, the specification is quite complex. It's certainly doable if you have the time and know what you are doing. And if you are lucky, and your JPEG blobs are all written the same way, you might get away with implementing only some of the spec. But even then, you will need to (re-)implement large parts of the spec, and it might just not be worth it.

Using a 3rd party service to convert it for you, or create your own using a known library, like libjpeg or Java's ImageIO, etc. might be your best bets, if you need a quick solution, and don't have too strict requirements for performance.

Comment: There's a javascript jpg decoder lib here that might run as an apps-script with a few adjustments: https://github.com/notmasteryet/jpgjs

Comment: @Nathan Actually, that looks like a very promising place to start!

Answer (score 0):

There are no straightfoward image processing capabilities available in Apps Script. You'll have either expose your Python as a web service and call it from Apps Script or use the Drive REST API to access the files from your Python app or use any api webservices.

GAE Python has Image processing capabilities check the below url:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/

Available image transformations

The Images service can resize, rotate, flip, and crop images, and enhance photographs. It can also composite multiple images into a single image.